# Joint Bilateral Filter Implementation

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I am trying to implement `Rolling Guidance Filter` [link](http://www.cse.cuhk.edu.hk/leojia/projects/rollguidance/paper/[ECCV2014]RollingGuidanceFilter_5M.pdf) but I can't find any implementation for Joint Bilateral Filter used in the RGF.

In my project I am using `OpenCV` in Java. Seems like Joint Bilateral Filter is there in one module named `XImgProc` for `C++`. So is there similar Module for Java which provides the particular Filter.

Also, if there is no such filter then I would like to understand how Joint Bilateral Filter works. So if that source is also provided my work can be done.

Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, java version of OpenCv lacks many modules. You can head in two directions - 1) since OCV is open source - look for C++ implementation on github and try to implement it in Java 2) there are many people trying to write their own opencv Java modules, try to search if this one is not the case as well

Comment: @Croolman Couldn't find. So writing my own.

Comment: You can also try and use JNI bindings to C++ code.

Comment: @arqam implemented? Or is there one available off the shelf yet?

Comment: How about cv2.[jointBilateralFilter](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/ximgproc/doc/edge_aware_filters.html#jointbilateralfilter)(joint, src, dst, d, sigmaColor, sigmaSpace[, borderType])